# How to add trailing slash if needed with gsub

Tags: ruby, gsub

I'm trying to add trailing slash if needed:

```
a = '/var/www'
a.gsub
...
```

I don't know how to do it.

Comment: I don't think I've ever needed to add a trailing slash in Ruby. Do you know about File.join? http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/File.html#M002545

Comment: It's also worthwhile learning about the `'pathname'` library which implements a whole algebra for working with pathnames.

Answer (score 26):

```
a = File.join(a, "")
```

Swift, simple, and has the effect of guaranteeing that `a` ends in a path separator; that is, it gives the same result whether `a` is `"/var/www"` or `"/var/www/"`.

This is same as Joe White's comment above; I don't know why he didn't submit it as an answer, as it deserves to be one.

Oddly, the Pathname library doesn't provide a convenient way of doing the same thing.

Comment: Functionally great, but I don't think I could put that in my code without adding a comment.

Answer (score 14):

Here's a bit more readable version

```
path << '/' unless path.end_with?('/')
```

Answer (score 2):

Why do you want to use *gsub*?

1. You're not doing substitution (nothing is to be removed from the string)
2. *If* you're substituting, and only need it done in one place, use `sub` not `gsub`.
3. *If* you're substituting, and want to modify the string, use `sub!` or `gsub!`.

Since you're not doing substitution, just append the slash if needed:

```
path << '/' if path[-1] != '/' # Make sure path ends with a slash
```

**Update:** To make it compatible with older versions of Ruby (1.8.x), modify it slightly:

```
path << '/' if path[-1].chr != '/' # Make sure path ends with a slash
```

Comment: That wont work as a[-1] will return the character code, not the character, you want something more like: a << '/' if a[-1].chr != '/'

Comment: @darkliquid: It works in Ruby 1.9. Updated my answer, thanks.

Comment: Another route to 1.8 compatibility is path << '/' unless path[-1..-1] == '/'.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.chomp('/')` to strip of the optionally trailing `/` and then `.concat('/')` to append a slash again.

```rb
'/var/www/'.chomp('/').concat('/')   # => "/var/www/"
'/var/www'.chomp('/').concat('/')    # => "/var/www/"
```

Answer (score 0):

The following script shows how this can be done:

```
a="/var/www";
print a + "\n";
a = a.gsub(/([^\/]$)/, '\1/');
print a + "\n";
a = a.gsub(/([^\/]$)/, '\1/');
print a + "\n";
```

It outputs:

```
/var/www
/var/www/
/var/www/
```

and works by substituting the last character of the line (if it's not a `/`) with the same character plus a trailing `/` as well.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of different ways that have already been covered, to through another into the mix:

```
(a << '/').gsub!('//','/')
```

or

```
(a << '/').squeeze('/')
```

It's worth noting though that both of those will convert any cases of '//' to '/' anywhere in the string, though if you are just dealing with paths, that's unlikely to cause problems.

Answer (score 0):

```
"/var/www".gsub(/[^\/]$/, '\1/')  #=> "/var/www/"
"/var/www/".gsub(/[^\/]$/, '\1/') #=> "/var/www/"
```

Comment: "example.com".gsub(/[^\/]$/, '\1/') #=> "example.co/"

Answer (score 0):

Pretty simple gsub, which is easier as a one liner than the concatenation (<<)

```
a = '/var/www'
a.gsub('/?$', '/')
```

This simply finds an optional `/` character at the end of the string and rep